# How to find all combinations of 6 tasks

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If I have 6 tasks that need to be assigned to at most 6 work stations, is there a way of working out all possible solutions?

For example, assuming tasks are names 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, you could have

- all on separate stations or all on the same
- station 1: 1,2,3 station 2: 4,5,6
- station 1: 1,2 station 2: 3 station 3: 4,5 station 4: 6

I know if you have 1 task there is one option, for 2 there are 2, for 3 there are 5, for 4 there are 15 and for 5 I believe 36 options however as it is growing at such a vast rate I am hoping to find a rule to work this out for any number and would appreciate any guidance. The order is not important as the tasks can be done in any order so station 1:1,2,3 and station 2:4,5,6 would be the same result as station 1:4,5,6 station 2:1,2,3 and only count as 1 option. In my head there should be a rule for this but I so far cannot work it out.

Thank you in advance for any support!

Comment: Sorry, but question sounds confusing. Is the number of workstations fixed? If not, is there any relation between the number of tasks and the workstations? Like, are they always equal in number?

Comment: Also, do you have a background in math? Or do you just want a simple formula you can work out using an ordinary calculator?

Comment: Just noticed this too, my answer covers this for a fixed number of workstations. In practice, you wouldn't have an infinite number of workstations anyway, but it would be nice to have some clarity from OP.

Comment: Hi, apologies for the confusion, there is no relation, it is for an assembly line balancing problem where I need to know how many iterations for any number of workstations between 1 and 6, I do not have a full background of maths, just A level maths and further maths, and am currently doing a masters in engineering so much more applied maths.

Comment: @BellaAlcock So, you can use at most $6$ workstations and there can be any number of tasks in total. Order is not important. And the example you gave is - "station $1:1,2,3$ and station $2:4,5,6$ would be the same result as station $1:4,5,6$ station $2:1,2,3$ and only count as $1$ option." I understand the order of tasks on a workstation is also immaterial. So, $1,2,3$ is the same as $2,1,3$. But what about this? ...cont ↓

Comment: Say station $1$ gets tasks $1,2$ and station $2$ gets $3,4$ in one iteration. In another iteration station $1$ gets $1,4$ and the station $2$ gets $2,3$. Are these distinct or will they be considered the same? Because in both cases the two workstations have $2$ tasks each, just different tasks.

Comment: I should warn you that this is a challenging problem and even after all the details, we may not be able to help you much or at all.

Comment: @Haris Yes so the max number if work stations is equivalent to the number of tasks, and the minimum is one assuming all tasks are on the same station. I appreciate it is a challenging problem so apologise for this. The example you gave would be considered as two iterations as the assigned tasks are different, which I think is where my problem lies. It would be the same for case 1: station 1 to have 1, 2 and station 2 to have 3,4 and case 2: station 1 has 3,4 and station 2 to have 1,2. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: See [twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way) and [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

Answer (score 0):

Changing my answer now that I better understand the question thanks to the added comments.

From my understanding, you have $n$ stations and $n$ tasks to give out to them, such that every station has exactly one of the tasks and no two stations can have the same task.
As you're looking for the number of ways this is possible, a way of representing this would be as the number of families of $n$ vectors from $\lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace^n$ such that :
$$\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n}{v_i} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Each vector would correspond to a station, and the $1$s in each position correspond to one of the tasks. This obviously isn't necessary but it helped me with visualising what I'll present below :

As an example, for $n = 3$, consider :
$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ b_1 \\ c_1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} a_2 \\ b_2 \\ c_2 \end{pmatrix}, \quad v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} a_3 \\ b_3 \\ c_3 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \text{ with } a_i, b_i, c_i \in \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace$$

- If any station has no tasks, one of the vectors above is full of $0$s, so there are $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = 1$ ways of selecting such a vector.
  But then the others must have $3$ of the remaining $1$s.
  We only need to consider the second to last station, since the last one will be constrained to have all the remaining tasks.
  One of the stations can have no tasks, or one task (not more, since the other station will already have three or two respectively) and as you may know this sum of binomial coefficients yields $2^{3-1} = 4$. We must not forget to multiply this result by the number of ways of choosing none from the first station (which was $1$).
- If no station had no tasks, you can repeat this kind of iteration, and will find that only the case where each station had one task remains. This indeed gives $5$ combinations like your original post states.

Now, taking any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, you can actually notice using the argument I presented above that the calculation gets a lot bulkier, but you can reduce it to :
$$\sum_{M \in \mathcal{M}}{\prod_{1 \leq k \leq \lvert M \rvert}{\begin{pmatrix} n-\sum_{i=1}^k{m_i} \\ m_k \end{pmatrix} \left(1-\frac{\delta_{m, n-\lvert M \rvert}}{2} \right)}}$$

where $\mathcal{M}$ can be seen as the set of all sets of distinct $n-1$ integers in $\lbrace 0, \dots, \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor \rbrace$ that sum to $n$ or less.
The need for them to be distinct is because if you have multiple stations that have the same number of tasks, then they are interchangeable, and the need for the integers to be smaller than $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor$ is because otherwise you could have repeats despite $m$s being different, due to the symmetry of binomial coefficients.
As if it wasn't complicated enough, in an edit to this answer, I added a Kronecker delta term $\delta_{m, n-\lvert M \rvert}$, as if the combination of tasks you pick leaves the last station having the same number of tasks as one of the previous stations, they are interchangeable.

If you do not know the Kronecker delta, it is defined in this context as :
$$\delta_{m, n-\lvert M \rvert} = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if } m \neq n - \lvert M \rvert \\ 1 &\text{ if } m = n - \lvert M \rvert \end{cases}$$

The reason we don't include $n$ terms in $\mathcal{M}$'s definition is because the $n$-th vector implied by the product of $n-1$ binomial coefficients will fill in whatever gap is left by the sum of all the $m$ integers.

I know this way of presenting it is technical but as Haris has stated, it's not an easy problem, and you *can* definitely compute it for small $n$ as you have noticed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris, this has definitely shown hope that this is solvable. Over the day I manually worked it out as n=6 then the options are 203 (it was tedious) so I will test this to see if my answer is correct. I will also have to spend some time working out exactly what you have done but this is really helpful thank you so much!

Comment: I need to clarify that I tried out the formula I provided and it's noticeably wrong, so I'll edit my answer when I figure out how to fix it. I wrote $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ m \end{pmatrix}$ in the sum but it seems that as the stations are interchangeable in the model there is no need for combinatorials for this specifically, and that makes sense seeing how quickly the number blows up in the current formula.

Comment: @BellaAlcock I've updated the formula, it's a bit more complicated but more accurate in what it portrays. There is something I still have trouble formalising, as for example, the product of binomial coefficients given by $M = \lbrace 0,0,0,1,3 \rbrace$ corresponds exactly to the one given by $M = \lbrace 0,0,0,1,2 \rbrace$, as including the implied $n$-th station in each of them will reveal.
However annoying this is, I'm not sure of how to get rid of it in writing, and the only way I can avoid it currently is by simply noticing these cases when they arise, and ignoring them (which is bad).

Comment: Thank you Chris! Really appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

From your description and the results you obtained up to $n=6$, it seems you are counting the number of [partitions of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) (though you seem to have made a mistake for $n=5$, where there are $52$ partitions, not $36$).

The number of ways to partition a set with $n$ elements into subsets is the $n$-th [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number). The Wikipedia article provides many ways to calculate these numbers, as does the corresponding [OEIS sequence A000110](https://oeis.org/A000110). One practical option for the small values of $n$ you’re dealing with is the recurrence relation

$$
B_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkB_k\;.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I realised after that I have made a mistake with 5 I just hadn’t got round to correcting it yet but thank you!